# Having problems with my javascript function returning a value

Tags: javascript, html

I have trouble with my javascript function return the correct value. So basically, what I expected to turn up was one of the prices from the tour_prices-arraylist. But actually nothing is showing up. Any help is appreciated.

```js
var tour_prices = new Array();
tour_prices["0"]=3000;
tour_prices["1"]=4400;
tour_prices["2"]=5500;
tour_prices["3"]=6600;
tour_prices["4"]=7700;

function tourPrice() {
  var thePrice = 0;
  var scheme = document.forms["orderScheme"];
  var pickDestination = scheme.elements["destination"];
  thePrice = tour_prices[pickDestination.value];

  return thePrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var totalTourPrice = tourPrice();
  
  var totalPrice = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  totalPrice.innerHTML = "the total tour price is " + totalTourPrice + " usd.";
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="orderScheme" onsubmit="return false">
  <div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Order cruise!</legend>
    <b><label>Pick Destination: </label></b>
    <select id="destination" name='destination' onchange="calculateTotal()">
      <option value="0">destination 1</option>
      <option value="1">destination 2</option>
      <option value="2">destination 3</option>
      <option value="3">destination 4</option>
      <option value="4">destination 5</option>
    </select>
   </fieldset>
  <div id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice"></div><br>
       
<input type='submit' id='submit' value='calculate' onclick="calculateTotal()"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: `tourPrice()();`  <-- wrong

Comment: Yeah, my bad. That's not in the actual code tho :)

Comment: The code works as posted, where is the issue?

Comment: The problem was that the 'calculateTotal' didn't return the value from tourPrice(). Even though the .selectedIndex, is not needed according to you, it solved the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` doesn't have a `value` of its own -- you need to find the selected `option` (via the `selectedIndex` property), then get *its* value.

```js
var tour_prices = new Array();
tour_prices["0"]=3000;
tour_prices["1"]=4400;
tour_prices["2"]=5500;
tour_prices["3"]=6600;
tour_prices["4"]=7700;

function tourPrice() {
  var thePrice = 0;
  var scheme = document.forms["orderScheme"];
  var pickDestination = scheme.elements["destination"];
  var val = pickDestination.options[ pickDestination.selectedIndex ].value;
  thePrice = tour_prices[val];

  return thePrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var totalTourPrice = tourPrice();
  
  var totalPrice = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  totalPrice.innerHTML = "the total tour price is " + totalTourPrice + " usd.";
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="orderScheme" onsubmit="return false">
  <div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Order cruise!</legend>
    <b><label>Pick Destination: </label></b>
    <select id="destination" name='destination' onchange="calculateTotal()">
      <option value="0">destination 1</option>
      <option value="1">destination 2</option>
      <option value="2">destination 3</option>
      <option value="3">destination 4</option>
      <option value="4">destination 5</option>
    </select>
   </fieldset>
  <div id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice"></div><br>
       
<input type='submit' id='submit' value='calculate' onclick="calculateTotal()"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Paul Roub: Thank you, so much!

Comment: "*The select doesn't have a value of its own*" is incorrect. The value of a select element is the value of the selected option. If no option is selected, the value will be "" (empty string). The use of the *selectedIndex* property hasn't been necessary since about Netscape 5, but persists as some kind of meme.

Comment: Having been at this since Netscape 2, certain habits stick around. You're correct, in anything vaguely modern, of course. The typo alone appears to have been the real problem.

Comment: selectIndex might not be needed, but it solved the problem I was having where calculateTotal() wouldn't calculate and write it to div id="totalPrice"